# Using mutation to filter in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

i am trying to filter out my table using vuex. I am new to vuex so trying to understand how exactly it works. I have a data table which is one component and a search field which is a separate component. I am  trying to filter data from the table but how can i do it using vuex?

I have made a codepen for illustration but i don't know how to use store in a codepen or make separate components:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXWGpG?editors=1010. Hopefully this gives you an idea on what i am trying to achieve.

In my search field component i have:

```
   <template>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="search"
      append-icon="search"
      label="Search"
      single-line
      hide-details
    ></v-text-field>
    </template>

   <script>
    export default {
     data() {
       return {

       }
       },

       computed: {
       search() {
      return this.$store.state.search
         }
      }
     </script>
```

In my table component:-

```
       <div id="app">
     <v-app id="inspire">
         <v-card>
       <v-card-title>
     Nutrition
     <v-spacer></v-spacer>
     </v-card-title>
      <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :search="search"
         >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
       <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" color="error" 
       icon="warning">
        Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
       </v-alert>
     </v-data-table>
     </v-card>
   </v-app>
   </div>


   new Vue({
     el: '#app',
      data () {
      return {
      headers: [
    {
      text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'name'
    },
    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
    { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
    { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
  ],
  desserts: [
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: '1%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
      calories: 237,
      fat: 9.0,
      carbs: 37,
      protein: 4.3,
      iron: '1%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Eclair',
      calories: 262,
      fat: 16.0,
      carbs: 23,
      protein: 6.0,
      iron: '7%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Cupcake',
      calories: 305,
      fat: 3.7,
      carbs: 67,
      protein: 4.3,
      iron: '8%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Gingerbread',
      calories: 356,
      fat: 16.0,
      carbs: 49,
      protein: 3.9,
      iron: '16%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Jelly bean',
      calories: 375,
      fat: 0.0,
      carbs: 94,
      protein: 0.0,
      iron: '0%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Lollipop',
      calories: 392,
      fat: 0.2,
      carbs: 98,
      protein: 0,
      iron: '2%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Honeycomb',
      calories: 408,
      fat: 3.2,
      carbs: 87,
      protein: 6.5,
      iron: '45%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'Donut',
      calories: 452,
      fat: 25.0,
      carbs: 51,
      protein: 4.9,
      iron: '22%'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: 'KitKat',
      calories: 518,
      fat: 26.0,
      carbs: 65,
      protein: 7,
      iron: '6%'
       }
     ]
    }
  }
 })
```

And in my store.js file

```
     state: {
       search: ''
     },
     mutations: {

           }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may not be the best fit for vuex as it is. The data would need to be in vuex, and then you would use an action(optional) and mutation to modify the filter, which would update the result. The benefit is that other components can access the filtered result, but in this case that doesn't seem like something that you'd need outside of that component. Also, your vuetify table already handles the search internally, so it's not needed, and unclear whether you want to just store the search for future use, or do the filtering in vuex.

Comment: @Daniel I want to have it perform the filter in vuex and pass it to the data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `search` from store's state and bind it to table's component:

```
computed: {
  search() {
    return this.$store.state.search
  }
}
```

Then you can use `search` in v-data-table

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :search="search"
/>
```

To use 2-way mutation using `computed`, you need to use get and set

```
computed: {
  search: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.search
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateSearch', value)
    }
  }
}
```

and in your store, create the mutation

```
mutations: {
  updateSearch (state, payload) {
    state.search = payload
  }
}
```

Comment: So i wouldn't need to mutate the state? Just the state by itself will do?

Comment: You only need mutate state in search component. In table component, you should read only.

Comment: I get an error message that the search was assigned to the text field but it has no setter.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what i needed. If you don't mind could you please explain how, when and why to use 2 way mutation?

Comment: You can read more here https://itnext.io/anyway-this-is-how-to-use-v-model-with-vuex-computed-setter-in-action-320eb682c976